# Firebase database Permission denied error facing using swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
guard let uid = user?.uid  else {return}

let usernameValue = ["username":username]
let value = [uid: usernameValue]

Database.database().reference().child("user").updateChildValues(value, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
    if let err = err{
        print("failed to save user in db:", err)
    }else{
        print("successfully Work")
    }
})
```

This is the error I am facing:

> failed to save user in db: Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the permission to manage the `/user` path in the database.

Check your Firebase security rules.

Comment: service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write:if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: How set rule here

Comment: { match /databases/{database}/documents { match /{document=**} { allow read, write; } } }

Comment: The above rule is only for testing purposes. It must be changed on production. Check this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: I have just noticed that you are using Realtime Database code and showing Firestore rules in the comment. Firestore rules have no effect on Realtime Database. You must either check your Realtime Database security rules or use Firestore code in your project

Answer (score 0):

Allow unauthenticated access to your database.

Go into the Database panel in the console for you project, select the Rules tab and replace the contents with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

This makes your new database readable and writeable by everyone.

One more trick to avoid this problem call one of the signIn...methods of Firebase Authentication to ensure the user is signed in before accessing the database.